# finding out the referenced value of a cell in excel

Tags: vba, excel, reference, excel-formula

I have an excel file with several worksheets

the worksheet is littered with formulas in each cell which reference cells in other worksheets such as:

in WS1 in cell A1 it has `=+WS2!B2`

in WS2 in cell B2 it has `=+WS3!C3`

and in C3 it says `=D4*50`

Is there a way to have cell A1 in WS1 to be `=D4*50` ? or atleast show that to me?

The closest I could do is click on `Evaluate Formula` which will traverse through the reference and cells

[image]

Is there something like this but for many cells?

Comment: You want this in VBA?

Comment: I prefer in some other way, but if in VBA which is able to show me that final value in a click and revert back to the calculated value - then sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Formula tab, Trace Dependent and Trace precedents can help you..

Comment: This works almost well. It doesn't handle references to other worksheets very well, unfortunatly. It shows an icon of a worksheet which leads me to nowhere. Am I missing something?

Comment: It draws a dashed line to another sheet, if you double-click on the line it will open the "Go to" dialog box with the cell reference shown. If you click on that you go to the cell on that sheet.